# Wordpress and CSV file. Can it work ?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, csv

I have a small problem. On my wordpress based website I want to create an Order-Status form where people can use a code and check their order's progress. It's not an online store so I don't use woocommerce. The file containing the order's progress is a CSV file. 
I tried to use that through a  function but didn't work. I even tried Javascript but my code can't find the file on server :( 
My question is: What language and what technique should I use for my need.

Thank a lot guyz.

Comment: You might want to add some of your code here, to get the ball rolling. A quick initial suggestion is to check out https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for without the need of any libraries:

First You create a form (the form action can be your homepage since we will be listening for the $_GET parameters on `init`, which is run on every page load):

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="csv_export" value="order_status" />
    <input type="text" name="code" />
    <input type="submit" value="Download Report" name="download_report" />
</form>
```

Than you need to add an action on `init` in functions.php to listen for the get parameter `csv_export` in order to start your functionality to prepare the csv file and output it for download: (we are using the exit(); function after we create csv to make sure that nothing else runs after this process.)

```
function check_for_export() {
    if ( isset( $_GET['csv_export'], $_GET['code'] ) && $_GET['csv_export'] == 'order_status' ) {
            ob_end_clean();
            export_order_status_csv( $_GET['code'] );
            exit();
        }
    }
}
add_action('init', 'check_for_export');
```

Now you can start the functionality to generate the csv report. This function depends on how you are fetching the data but you can follow this example to set the headers and output the report:

```
function export_order_status_csv( $code ) {

    // Make a DateTime object and get a time stamp for the filename
    $date = new DateTime();
    $ts = $date->format( "Y-m-d-G-i-s" );

    // A name with a time stamp, to avoid duplicate filenames
    $filename = "order-statuses-export-$ts.csv";

    // Tells the browser to expect a CSV file and bring up the
    // save dialog in the browser
    header( 'Pragma: public' );
    header( 'Expires: 0' );
    header( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0' );
    header( 'Content-Description: File Transfer' );
    header( 'Content-Type: text/csv' );
    header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=' . $filename );
    header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' );

    // This opens up the output buffer as a "file"
    $fp = fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );

    //This needs to be customised from your end, I am doing a WP_Query for this example
    $results = new WP_Query();  
    if ( $results->have_posts() ) {

        //This is set to avoid issues with special characters
        $bom = ( chr( 0xEF ) . chr( 0xBB ) . chr( 0xBF ) );

        //add BOM to fix UTF-8 in Excel
        fputs( $fp, $bom );

        // Set the headers of the csv
        fputcsv( $fp, [
            'orderID',
            'orderDate',
            'orderTotal'
        ] );

        while ( $results->have_posts() ) {
            $results->the_post();

            //Here we are inserting the row data per result fetched
            fputcsv(
                $fp,
                [
                    get_the_ID(),
                    get_the_date(),
                    'your_custom_data'
                ]
            );

        }
        wp_reset_query();
        // Close the output buffer (Like you would a file)
        fclose( $fp );
    } else {
        fputcsv( $fp, [ 'No Results' ] );
        fclose( $fp );
    }

}
```

**When exporting a csv you have to hook to an action which is processed before anything has been outputted. There cannot be any output before creating the csv file since we are updating the headers.**

If you want to read the data from a csv file and manipulate it to customise your csv export you can use this function instead of the WP_Query in example above: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: This is very useful and you have the correct thinking. I probably didn't explain my issue well enough.
The CSV File does not need to be reprinted , replaced or saved again. All I need is to collate a code(given by the user) with the CSV file and GET the data for this specific line.

Comment: In order to read the data from the csv use the last part of the answer and check the code with the data fetched from the csv.

Answer (score 0):

I actually used [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) in a previous project that achieved what you're after, though I see it's been deprecated in favour of [PhpSpreadsheet library](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet). So I would use that one!

What both libraries can essentially do (amongst many other things) is parse the spreadsheet and return the relevant information based on what you request.

So you could put your spreadsheet in a separate directory which you then use the PhpSpreadsheet library to extract information from - and present to the customer in whatever way you see fit.