# Create CSV file from php string

Tags: php

I would like to create an CSV file using php with an semicolon at the end of each line.

The file should looke like this:

```
Smith,"Andreas",";"
Smith,"John",";"
```

I can not get the semicolon at the end of the line. I tried all sorts of masking, read articels in the net but I just can't get it to work.

That is the code I use:

```
$datei1 = fopen($file1,"w");

$query = "SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY cust_name";
$cust_name = $row['cust_name'];
$cust_firstname = $row['cust_firstname'];


$semicolon = ";";

$data = '"'.$cust_name.'","'.$cust_firstname.'","'.$semicolon.'"';

fwrite($datei1, $data);
fwrite($datei1, "\r\n");
```

Comment: Seems ok to me, what output are you getting that doesn't match your expectations?

Comment: Hi Federio, ist just shows the 1st line and stops when it detects the first semicolon. The output looks like adam,"andreas"," and all the other records are not written to the file.

Comment: Why not create an array, and use [fputcsv](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)?

Comment: No errors, no warnings, nothing? Also, if it stops after the first line it's because you're not looping over results.

Comment: No error messages at all. I guess php stops when it detects the first semicolon. I tried to mask it, but I could not get it to work.

Comment: why don't you try fputcsv this is very useful way to create the csv file.

Comment: Have a look at this in order to use fputcsv: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49342548/wordpress-and-csv-file-can-it-work/49345538

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think semicolon is a problem here, it shows only the first line because you don't loop on your queries

```
$datei1 = fopen($file1,"w");

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY cust_name",$db);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
    $mydata = [ $row['cust_name'] , $row['cust_firstname'] , ';'];
    fputcsv($datei1,$mydata,",");
}

fclose($datei1);
```

Comment: Hi Gourgandine, you are absolutely right. Your script did the trick! Thank you ever so much for your help. I really do appreciate it. Kind regards, Imbi